# Why does running this script in ZSH infinite loop and change the mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, zsh

I wrote a script, and forgot to put an important crunch-bang at the top to tell my Linux OS that it was a Node.js script:

```js
// @ts-check

import options from 'commander'
import fs from 'fs'

console.log(options, fs)

options
  .option('-i --input <input-file>', 'Input file to rename.')
  .option('-o --output <output-file>', 'What to rename the input file to.')
  .parse(process.argv)

async function rename() {
  await fs.promises.rename(options.input, options.output)
}

rename().catch(e => {
  console.error('')
  console.error(e)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Then, I tried to execute it like this in my ZSH shell:

```sh
chmod +x ./rename.mjs
./rename.mjs -i test.foo -o foo.test
```

As soon as I ran the file, my computer when crazy and locked up. Eventually it quit with this output once I interacted enough (pressing ctrl+c and mouse clicks):

```
❯ ./rename.mjs -i test.foo -o foo.test
./rename.mjs: line 1: //: Is a directory
import: unable to grab mouse '': No such file or directory @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9301.
import: unable to read X window image '': Success @ error/xwindow.c/XImportImage/4933.
import: unable to read X window image '': Success @ error/xwindow.c/XImportImage/5040.
import: unable to grab mouse '': No such file or directory @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9301.
import: unable to read X window image '': Success @ error/xwindow.c/XImportImage/4933.
import: unable to read X window image '': Success @ error/xwindow.c/XImportImage/5040.
import: unable to grab mouse '': No such file or directory @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9301.
import: unable to read X window image '': Success @ error/xwindow.c/XImportImage/4933.
import: unable to read X window image '': Success @ error/xwindow.c/XImportImage/5040.
import:  `fs' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1273.
./rename.mjs: line 6: options: command not found
./rename.mjs: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `'-i --input <input-file>','
./rename.mjs: line 7: `  .option('-i --input <input-file>', 'Input file to rename.')'
```

It tried to run this JS code as a ZSH script.

The weird thing, is it changes the mouse on the screen to look like a tiny plus icon!

After trying it a few times, I realized that if I do not interact with the mouse (by clicking) then it will loop forever and my Gnome 3 desktop is completely locked up, CPU spinning, fans spinning.

Once I click a few times, on each click the mouse goes back to my normal icon, and eventually the app quits with error.

I can not reproduce the original output above, but each time I try it now, I get this output:

```
❯ ./rename.mjs -i test.foo -o foo.test
./rename.mjs: line 1: //: Is a directory
./rename.mjs: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `options,'
./rename.mjs: line 6: `console.log(options, fs)'
```

Here's what my cursor looks like normally:

[image]

While the script is running (the system is Gnome desktop is frozen and won't unfreeze if I don't click the mouse), the cursor looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the cursor is now a tiny plus-like icon!

What is this script doing?

EDIT: I see it outputted a file with the name `commander` containing this:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Creator: (ImageMagick)
%%Title: (commander)
%%CreationDate: (2020-07-17T03:29:55+00:00)
%%%%BoundingBox: (atend)
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 1
%%Orientation: Portrait
%%PageOrder: Ascend
%%Pages: 3
%%EndComments

%%BeginDefaults
%%EndDefaults

%%BeginProlog
%
% Display a color image.  The image is displayed in color on
% Postscript viewers or printers that support color, otherwise
% it is displayed as grayscale.
%
/DirectClassPacket
{
  %
  % Get a DirectClass packet.
  %
  % Parameters:
  %   red.
  %   green.
  %   blue.
  %   length: number of pixels minus one of this color (optional).
  %
  currentfile color_packet readhexstring pop pop
  compression 0 eq
  {
    /number_pixels 3 def
  }
  {
    currentfile byte readhexstring pop 0 get
    /number_pixels exch 1 add 3 mul def
  } ifelse
  0 3 number_pixels 1 sub
  {
    pixels exch color_packet putinterval
  } for
  pixels 0 number_pixels getinterval
} bind def

/DirectClassImage
{
  %
  % Display a DirectClass image.
  %
  systemdict /colorimage known
  {
    columns rows 8
    [
      columns 0 0
      rows neg 0 rows
    ]
    { DirectClassPacket } false 3 colorimage
  }
  {
    %
    % No colorimage operator;  convert to grayscale.
    %
    columns rows 8
    [
      columns 0 0
      rows neg 0 rows
    ]
    { GrayDirectClassPacket } image
  } ifelse
} bind def

/GrayDirectClassPacket
{
  %
  % Get a DirectClass packet;  convert to grayscale.
  %
  % Parameters:
  %   red
  %   green
  %   blue
  %   length: number of pixels minus one of this color (optional).
  %
  currentfile color_packet readhexstring pop pop
  color_packet 0 get 0.299 mul
  color_packet 1 get 0.587 mul add
  color_packet 2 get 0.114 mul add
  cvi
  /gray_packet exch def
  compression 0 eq
  {
    /number_pixels 1 def
  }
  {
    currentfile byte readhexstring pop 0 get
    /number_pixels exch 1 add def
  } ifelse
  0 1 number_pixels 1 sub
  {
    pixels exch gray_packet put
  } for
  pixels 0 number_pixels getinterval
} bind def

/GrayPseudoClassPacket
{
  %
  % Get a PseudoClass packet;  convert to grayscale.
  %
  % Parameters:
  %   index: index into the colormap.
  %   length: number of pixels minus one of this color (optional).
  %
  currentfile byte readhexstring pop 0 get
  /offset exch 3 mul def
  /color_packet colormap offset 3 getinterval def
  color_packet 0 get 0.299 mul
  color_packet 1 get 0.587 mul add
  color_packet 2 get 0.114 mul add
  cvi
  /gray_packet exch def
  compression 0 eq
  {
    /number_pixels 1 def
  }
  {
    currentfile byte readhexstring pop 0 get
    /number_pixels exch 1 add def
  } ifelse
  0 1 number_pixels 1 sub
  {
    pixels exch gray_packet put
  } for
  pixels 0 number_pixels getinterval
} bind def

/PseudoClassPacket
{
  %
  % Get a PseudoClass packet.
  %
  % Parameters:
  %   index: index into the colormap.
  %   length: number of pixels minus one of this color (optional).
  %
  currentfile byte readhexstring pop 0 get
  /offset exch 3 mul def
  /color_packet colormap offset 3 getinterval def
  compression 0 eq
  {
    /number_pixels 3 def
  }
  {
    currentfile byte readhexstring pop 0 get
    /number_pixels exch 1 add 3 mul def
  } ifelse
  0 3 number_pixels 1 sub
  {
    pixels exch color_packet putinterval
  } for
  pixels 0 number_pixels getinterval
} bind def

/PseudoClassImage
{
  %
  % Display a PseudoClass image.
  %
  % Parameters:
  %   class: 0-PseudoClass or 1-Grayscale.
  %
  currentfile buffer readline pop
  token pop /class exch def pop
  class 0 gt
  {
    currentfile buffer readline pop
    token pop /depth exch def pop
    /grays columns 8 add depth sub depth mul 8 idiv string def
    columns rows depth
    [
      columns 0 0
      rows neg 0 rows
    ]
    { currentfile grays readhexstring pop } image
  }
  {
    %
    % Parameters:
    %   colors: number of colors in the colormap.
    %   colormap: red, green, blue color packets.
    %
    currentfile buffer readline pop
    token pop /colors exch def pop
    /colors colors 3 mul def
    /colormap colors string def
    currentfile colormap readhexstring pop pop
    systemdict /colorimage known
    {
      columns rows 8
      [
        columns 0 0
        rows neg 0 rows
      ]
      { PseudoClassPacket } false 3 colorimage
    }
    {
      %
      % No colorimage operator;  convert to grayscale.
      %
      columns rows 8
      [
        columns 0 0
        rows neg 0 rows
      ]
      { GrayPseudoClassPacket } image
    } ifelse
  } ifelse
} bind def

/DisplayImage
{
  %
  % Display a DirectClass or PseudoClass image.
  %
  % Parameters:
  %   x & y translation.
  %   x & y scale.
  %   label pointsize.
  %   image label.
  %   image columns & rows.
  %   class: 0-DirectClass or 1-PseudoClass.
  %   compression: 0-none or 1-RunlengthEncoded.
  %   hex color packets.
  %
  gsave
  /buffer 512 string def
  /byte 1 string def
  /color_packet 3 string def
  /pixels 768 string def

  currentfile buffer readline pop
  token pop /x exch def
  token pop /y exch def pop
  x y translate
  currentfile buffer readline pop
  token pop /x exch def
  token pop /y exch def pop
  currentfile buffer readline pop
  token pop /pointsize exch def pop
  x y scale
  currentfile buffer readline pop
  token pop /columns exch def
  token pop /rows exch def pop
  currentfile buffer readline pop
  token pop /class exch def pop
  currentfile buffer readline pop
  token pop /compression exch def pop
  class 0 gt { PseudoClassImage } { DirectClassImage } ifelse
  grestore
  showpage
} bind def
%%EndProlog
%%Page:  1 1
%%PageBoundingBox: 0 0 3840 2048
DisplayImage
0 0
3840 2048
12
3840 2048
0
0
1D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D2224
1D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D22241D2224
...
21252B21252B21252B21252B21252B21252B21252B21252B21252B

%%PageTrailer
%%Trailer
%%BoundingBox: -0 -0 3839 2047
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 3840 2048
%%EOF
```

Comment: Without the `#!` line at the top, the contents is executed as shell-commands in the current shell.  `import` is part of the imagemagick toolkit; it takes screenshots -- without parameters the cursor changes to let you know you can mark the area to grab

Comment: Wow, interesting! Indeed, it create output text files with 1.9 million lines (mostly numbers, but text at top and bottom containing `ImageMagick` stuff). I added the sample output.

Comment: @trusktr : While TomRegner is basically right, in particular about explaining the _import_ part, it does not look to me that your script was really run by `zsh`, because if it were, the error messages would be slightly different. Zsh would prepend them by writing `zsh:` in front, and your line `// @ts-check` should produce the message _zsh: permission denied: //_  and not `./rename.mjs: line 1: //: Is a directory`. Actually, the shell-related error messages look to me as if `sh` was running your script.

Comment: @user1934428 Interesting. I don't know what that is, but I'm in ZSH and I ran `./rename.mjs -i test.foo -o foo.test` at the command line.

Comment: @trusktr : It depends on the #! line of `rename.mjs` what program is used to run it. However, the code you posted is not zsh anyway, so basically it should *not* be run as zsh-script. You have not posted anything about `rename.mjs`, but I see that you tagged your question as `javascript`. If it is a server-side `javascript` program, you need to run it by javascript.

Comment: @trusktr: Maybe [this](https://www.pcsuggest.com/run-javascript-from-command-line-linux/) helps.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks, I know, I later added the `#!/usr/bin/env node`. Interesting that it doesn't execute as ZSH by default without a crunchbang, if I'm in ZSH.

Comment: Why should it? Without a crunchbang, the shell does not know what language the script is written, so the default applies, which is  typically plain `sh`. At least this is how it is done on my platform. Of course one could wish that it would rather abort with an error message, but I think this is just inheritage from the past: Long time ago, you had only sh, and every script was therefore sh. If a file does not have a known magic number in the first two bytes, it was simply run as (sh-)script. The `#!` magic was, AFIK, introduced with the advent of csh.

Comment: @user1934428 Interesting. Thanks!